# SQL Server Stored Procedure append parameters format

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, formatting

I have a stored procedure. I wanted to append the parameters to get all data from a specific table (e.g. `tblJanuary2014`). But the formatting is (probably) incorrect?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportAsOf
(   
    @Month varchar(15),
    @Year varchar(15)
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tbl@Month@Year
    RETURN
    END
```

During execution it says:

> Invalid object name 'tbl@Month@Year'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create dynamic sql on this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportAsOf
(   
    @Month varchar(15),
    @Year varchar(15)
)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
        SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM tbl' + @Month + @Year
        EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
    RETURN
    END
```

Comment: Somebody could execute this SP thus: `EXEC GetReportAsOf @Month = ';DELETE Table1', @Year = ';DELETE Table2'`.